# Json object returned from php is empty

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit

I'm writing a script using php to upload images to my local server.
user will upload the images from android application and I'm using retrofit library to do so. I want to return the path and name generated for the image in php for further processing in android. The problem is the php script always return an empty json

PHP Script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['image'])) {


    $upload_folder = "Signatures"; // Name of the folder.
    $unique_name = microtime().uniqid(); // Name of the image. use time method to make it unique.
    $path = "$upload_folder/$unique_name.jpg";
    $Image = $_POST['image'];


    if (file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($Image)) != false) {


        $data = [ 'imagePath' => $path];
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( $data );
        exit;   
        } 

    else {
        $data = [ 'imagePath' => 'No image path'];
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( $data );
        exit; 
        }   
    }

else {

    $data = [ 'imagePath' => 'No image path'];
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( $data );
        exit;

}
```

?>

Retorift method signature

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST ("Images.php")
Call<JSONObject> uploadImage (@Field("image") String image );
```

Upload image method

```
 public void uploadImage(){

    String image =  imageToString(signatureView.getSignatureBitmap());

    IAPI iAPI = Application.getImage();
    Call<JSONObject> call = iAPI.uploadImage(image);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("test" , "is succ");

                try {

                    JSONObject responseJSON = response.body();
                    Log.d("test" , responseJSON.toString());
                    String path = responseJSON.getString("path");
                    if (path == null) {
                        Log.d("test" , "path is null");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("test" , "path not null");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("test" , e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("test" , "not  succ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("test", " in onFailure  - load image :" + t.getMessage() + t.toString());
        }
    });




}
```

It always throws an exception saying that there is no value for path.
And responseJSON.toString() in log prints empty [].

EDIT :

I have created my own model that contains property called imagePath and now it's wroking. Thank you all

Comment: Images are found in the $_FILES array and not the $_POST array! [See the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly No the image is sent to the post and i'm able to save them successfully , my only problem is returning a response from PHP to android

Comment: @rav Have you tried using "imagePath" instead of "path"?  That's what you have in the PHP.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes sorry it's a typo. org.json.JSONException: No value for imagePath